# definitive removing urls in a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a comment box and do not want people to post urls.

the site is written in c# asp.net

Comment: Then you should politely ask them not to do so.

Comment: You can use regular expressions to filter common URL patterns, but that still doesn't prevent users from posting URLs as there are many ways to express them (at least that's what spam email taught us). How about w w w dot example dot com?

Comment: ...or is your question about how to prevent users from inserting HTML so that they can post active hyperlinks?

Comment: @divo no, it shows plain text only. but i don't even want to show the url in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

[Regex to find URL within text](http://weblogs.asp.net/farazshahkhan/archive/2008/08/09/regex-to-find-url-within-text-and-make-them-as-link.aspx)